# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function message()

Tags: php

I am facing the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function message()

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function message() in /storage/ssd1/726/17342726/public_html/process.php:214
> Stack trace:
> #0 /storage/ssd1/726/17342726/public_html/process.php(14): doLogin()
> #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd1/726/17342726/public_html/process.php on line 214

Below is my process.php code on that function

```
function doLogin()
  {
  $email   = trim($_POST['USERNAME']);
  $upass   = trim($_POST['PASS']);
  $h_upass = sha1($upass);
 
  //it creates a new objects of member
  $applicant = new Applicants();
  //make use of the static function, and we passed to parameters
  $res = $applicant->applicantAuthentication($email, $h_upass);
  
  if ($res==true) 
    {
    message("You are now successfully login!","success");
    redirect(web_root."applicant/");
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Account does not exist! Please contact Administrator."; 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Where `message()` function is defined?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The message() function is in process.php. Which mean after the applicants success login it will shows the message.

Comment: Show message function code then

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Changing the php version solve the problem.